# How to create a pdf key tags in php

Tags: php, fpdf

May you please help is my first time doing PDF. I want to create a key tags that will fill in the whole PDF so that I can be able to cut them when i print it. I am failing to place a border outside the text to make a square or rectangle. The first three text must be bold the last test not bold.

I want to create something like this:
[image]

```
<?php
 $root =realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
 require($root.'/@services/fpdf/fpdf.php');
 $pdf = new FPDF();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->Line(10,10,45,10);
 $pdf->Line(10,10,10,25);
 $pdf->Line(10,10,45,10);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
 $pdf->Write(0.1,"Block E",0,'C');
 $pdf->Ln(3);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
 $pdf->Write(0.1,"Block / Unit - Area",0,'C');
 $pdf->Ln(3);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
 $pdf->Write(0.1,"Floor",0,'C');
 $pdf->Ln(3);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
 $pdf->Write(0.1,"Door No. Door No",0,'C');
 $pdf->Output();

 ?>
```

Comment: https://www.positronx.io/laravel-pdf-tutorial-generate-pdf-with-dompdf-in-laravel/

Comment: @Sumitkumar: I don't think this is about laravel 9, nor about DomPDF. But I agree, DomPDF is easier to use if you're familiar with HTML.

Comment: is not laravel, is for dompdf